# Using functions to remove decimal values for a column in a dataset using excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, xlsx

I am using a truncate function in Excel to remove decimal values. When I remove the original column even the truncated column is deleted.
How do I remove only original column?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a clever answer to this question, only copying the truncated values and pasting them into a new column using 'Paste Values'.

Then you can safely remove the original column or the numbers in it.